# iOS Web View Force Size

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading a web page with 100% div widths, but the page is being loaded bigger than it should be in my WebView.

Is there a way to tell the webpage that the device is only a certain size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use html meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scaleable=no" />
```

If you want to do something similar from Obj-C instead of the html:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: +1 and apparently there is an IB option for this as well. Thanks.